# Longest Convex Subsequence

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

Note, I already looked at this solution: [Longest convex subsequence in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664920/longest-convex-subsequence-in-an-array)

I've looked at the solution above but I fail to understand it. What I know is that the property for a convex subsequence is:

```
c[i] < (c[i-1] + c[i+1]) / 2
```

So given an input of: 2082 0 24719 1 383 4 20029 9 3781 16

The solution will be: 2082 0 1 4 9 16

Now, the solution I was proposing was O(n3)

```
public static int max(int... i){
    int max = 0;
    for(int n : i){
        if(n > max)
            max = n;
    }
    return max;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();

    int[] arr = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        arr[i] = in.nextInt();

    int[][][] LCS = new int[n][n][n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                LCS[i][j][k] = 0;
            }
        }

    }
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length-2; ++i){
        for(int j=1; j < arr.length-1;++j){
            for(int k = 2; k < arr.length; ++k){
                if(arr[j] < (arr[i]+arr[k])/2){
                     LCS[i][j][k] = max(LCS[i][j][k], 1+ LCS[i][j][k-1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int max = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                if(LCS[i][j][k] > max)
                    max = LCS[i][j][k];
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println(max);
}
```

I understand this is completely naive but I feel like I am on the right track, I'm not sure why but I keep getting a sequence of 8 for the answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The lookup table in the Memoization should be a two dimensional array.
The solution below is also O(n3). Any sequence of size 2 or less is also a convex subsequence. So, along the diagonal in the table, it will be filled with 2.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LongestConvexSubSequence {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length = in.nextInt();
    //System.out.println(length);
    int[] array = new int[length];
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        array[i] = in.nextInt();    



    System.out.println("Max = "+ longestConvex(array, length) );
}

public static int longestConvex(int[] array, int  n){
    if(n<=2)
        return n;

    int max = 0;
    int[][] B = new int[n][n];
    B[0][0] = 1;

    for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            B[i][j] = 2;
            for(int k=0; k<j; k++){
                if(B[j][k]+ 1 >B[i][j] && ((array[i] - array[j]) > (array[j] - array[k])))
                    B[i][j] = B[j][k] + 1;
            }
            max = Math.max(max, B[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return max;
}
}
```